# Unable to boot to Windows 7 successfully from the first try

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-10

I had Windows 10 installed along Ubuntu, and would choose from `grub` loader.

I later uninstalled Win 10 and installed Win 7 in its place, I updated `grub` in Ubuntu but the Windows 10 entry in grub did not go away.

I now have two entries, both entitled Windows 10, one in `/dev/sda1` and the other in `/dev/sda2`.

Both load Windows 7, but not on the first try. When I initially load it, the screen is dark, while Windows has loaded in the background (I can hear the sounds).

I have to power-off the computer, then choose Windows again for the screen to work. Sometimes I have to repeat this more than once.

I don't know much in Linux so I can't tell if the problem is from Windows or `grub`.

Comment: You ran `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu? Also, is Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes. Do you mean which 'mode I have in BIOS? I think it's legacy.

Comment: Usually Windows makes some other partitions alongside the main partition during the installation. Did you remove those partitions before installing Windows 7?

Comment: @Dante I fixed the issue, I'm not sure what exactly fixed it.

I disabled the graphic terminal from grub /etc/default/grub
.Grub detected Win 7 this time, I don't know why it didn't detect it the first time I updated it.

Maybe the graphics terminal option fixed it, maybe it wasn't relevant at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/536757/625501

Comment: Do you have a single or two or more hard disks?

Comment: @MichaelX when you say "sd1" above can we assume you mean `sda1`. To clarify can you  type `lsblk` in the terminal and paste the output in your question.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix As I've already said, I fixed the issue, the solution is in the link fossfreedom posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [GRUB2: black screen when booting Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536745/grub2-black-screen-when-booting-windows/536757#536757) but cannot be closed due to bounty rules. The solution as confirmed by OP in comments is:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Search for the following and change the second line to look like:

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Save and exit then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminal option isn't relevant.

If you've run `sudo update-grub` and the results are inconsistent, That points to a hardware problem with the storage media. I highly recommend that you [check the status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077) of your /dev/sda drive as you may have failing sectors buried under the MBR or under your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.